# Locate wp-config.php file after Word Press Click To Deploy on Google Compute Engine For Migration

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, migration, host

I have created a virtual machine on Google Cloud Platform that is running Wordpress, which was setup using Wordpress click-to-deploy: https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/wordpress?pli=1&_ga=2.72191571.-1784804083.1544815132&_gac=1.153409866.1545571350.Cj0KCQiAgf3gBRDtARIsABgdL3mwngvHYtz5GvkiA6vsknZDGdM8JIDPByT7v2O4m0tkvXXibVI0trAaAi37EALw_wcB

I am trying to migrate a my website over to GCP, and to export everything, I used All-in-One WP Migration. I have used this to export the website data, but when I go over to my new host and try to import the data, there it says that there is an file size limit for imports of 100 mb. I found that i need to increase the limit in my wp-config.php file (option 2): https://help.servmask.com/2018/10/27/how-to-increase-maximum-upload-file-size-in-wordpress/

However, I cannot find my wp-config.php anywhere on GCP or in the wordpress dashboard platform. How do I access this in order to increase my limit so that i can import the new file?

Comment: On linux you can `find` files. Run this command: `find / -name wp-config.php`. This will search the entire file system.

Comment: pho_pho - Did you ever figure out what to do? I'm trying to point my WP to a Cloud SQL instance so I need access to that file as well.

Comment: @DougKnesek, please see my answer below and let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using the Duplicator plugin for wordpress, instead of the All-in-One WP migration.

The Duplicator plugin will produce two files; an archive file and an installer file. This link here will tell you how to upload these:

https://snapcreek.com/duplicator/docs/quick-start/?utm_source=duplicator_free&utm_medium=wordpress_plugin&utm_content=package_built_install_help&utm_campaign=duplicator_free#quick-040-q

Answer (score 2):

I figured using this:

Go search here: /var/www/html/