# How to access the wp-config.php file (location) after a WordPress "Click To Deploy" on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I have created a virtual machine on Google Cloud Platform that is running Wordpress, which was setup using Wordpress click-to-deploy: https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/wordpress?pli=1&_ga=2.72191571.-1784804083.1544815132&_gac=1.153409866.1545571350.Cj0KCQiAgf3gBRDtARIsABgdL3mwngvHYtz5GvkiA6vsknZDGdM8JIDPByT7v2O4m0tkvXXibVI0trAaAi37EALw_wcB

However, I cannot find my **wp-config.php** anywhere on GCP or in the wordpress dashboard platform.

**How do I access this file in order to update it?**

this is a copy/adaptation of this original question : [Locate wp-config.php file after Word Press Click To Deploy on Google Compute Engine For Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162599/locate-wp-config-php-file-after-word-press-click-to-deploy-on-google-compute-eng)

but the answer given to that question pertains to the migration of files, not to the locating and updating of the wp-config.php file, so does not respond to my question.

thanks

Comment: For this deployment, the standard location is /var/www/html. However, not all deployments use standard locations (Bitnami is different). You can use a tool to find files `find / -type f -name wp-config.php -print`. Of course one option is to read the documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To locate this file you can:

- ssh into your instance (from the developer console for example)
- navigate to the /var/www/html directory by running `cd /var/www/html/`

You'll find there all the files related to your Wordpress installation